# Cannot add foreign key constraint in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, database-migration

I have an app where users belong to a team. Here is my test:

```
/** @test */
public function it_has_many_users()
{
    $team = factory(Team::class)->create();
    $users = factory(User::class, 3)->create([
        'team_id' => $team->getKey(),
    ]);

    $this->assertEquals(3, $team->users->count());
}
```

I have a foreign key setup on the users table like so:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('team_id')->nullable();

        $table->foreign('team_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('teams')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

There is more to the migration, but for simplicity I have only included the necessary code. Here is my `teams` migration:

```
Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
});
```

When I run my test I get this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_team_id_foreign` foreign key (`team_id`) references `teams` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)

I'm not sure what is wrong as I have other foreign keys set up the same way on other tables and they work fine. I do have all relationships set up correctly.

Comment: Silly question, but is teams earlier in the migration than users?  IE is teams actually a table when users is run?

Comment: teams migration is after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the team migration to earlier, before the user table migration happens.  Otherwise, there is no teams table in existence yet to reference when creating the user table, and thus the error.

IE

```
Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {...}
```

THEN

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {...}
```